# Conflicting libtinyxml libraries - Kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a recent update I now am getting lots of warnings from catkin/cmake:

```
CMake Warning at /home/dave/ros/current/ws_moveit/src/moveit/moveit_setup_assistant/CMakeLists.txt:132 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target
  moveit_setup_assistant_updater because files in some directories may
  conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    link library [libtinyxml.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/ros/kinetic/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

It seems Kinetic is now shipping with

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libtinyxml.so
```

But ROS debians still depend on the system version:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml2.so.2.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so.2.6.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml2.so.2
/usr/share/doc/libtinyxml2.6.2v5
/usr/share/doc/libtinyxml-dev
/usr/share/doc/libtinyxml2-2v5
```

How did duplicate happen? How can I remove the hundreds of warnings? It also seems to broken my build of ros-kinetic-srdfdom.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267743/conflicting-libtinyxml-libraries---kinetic/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the issue: https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/fzi_icl_core/issues/1

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2017-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-07-31**:
This isn't really an answer is it? I mean I guess it's the cause, but the solution there is to support both versions so it compiles. It doesn't address your linking warnings I think.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-07-31**:
I'm trying to track down which package is installing the tinyxml lib to `/opt/ros` now. I'd say we need to raise the issue on the issue tracker of the that package.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-07-31**:
nvm, I misread the issue. It is the one responsible, so once it is updated to work with the system one, it will no longer install its own. So this is the answer. Sorry for the noise.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2017-07-31**:
Thanks for your help William!